# JS - How can I implement gravity?

Tags: javascript, math, gravity, numerical-methods

How can I implement gravity? I have made this: http://jsfiddle.net/X2XvC/5/ but all dots simply follow your cursor (that's not gravitation). I heard about Eulers method, but I don't know how to implement it into my code.

what I found:

```
void update(float dt)
{
    position += velocity * dt + acceleration * 0.5 * dt * dt;
    velocity += acceleration * dt;
}
```

Comment: You have to affect your point "velocityY" values by the force of gravity. Each iteration, the "velocityY" must get smaller (less positive) by some amount, and the amount itself must get bigger over time on a per-point basis. Think about the basic physics of real gravity :)

Comment: I will see what I can do :)

Comment: Oh and note that since the coordinate system on a web page is upside down, conceptually "negative" velocity is actually positive!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Pointy already suggested, you have to affect the points' velocity vector.

Gravity is a force that is calculated by:

```
F_G = gamma * mass1 * mass2 / distance^2
```

Where `gamma` is the Gravitational constant and `mass1` and `mass2` are the objects' masses. You get the resulting acceleration with:

```
F_G = a * mass1
a = F_G / mass1
  = gamma * mass2 / distance^2
```

And you'll see that the acceleration is independent of the moving object's mass. What remains is `gamma * mass2` which you can set to an arbitrary constant. Whichever meets your needs best.

Now we have the length of the acceleration vector. The direction is of course `normalize(cursorPosition - pointPosition)`. So the overall acceleration is:

```
d = cursorPosition - pointPosition
a = constant * d / length(d)^3
```

Knowing this, you can update the point's velocity and speed in every frame by:

```
velocity += a * dt
position += velocity * dt
```

where `dt` is the duration of the last frame.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/X2XvC/10/) is your changed example code. The line `if(distance < 6)...` is used to cap the acceleration (if a point moves through the gravity center, it is infinitely accelerated).